# Role of a condition in selection sort?

Tags: c, sorting

What's the role of the statement marked below through a comment in the code fragment to implement Selection sort?

```
int temp, min;

for (i = 0; i <= count - 2; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1;  j <= count - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[min] > arr[j]) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[min]) {    //What's the significance of this statement?
                temp = arr[min];
                arr[min] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the significance of that statement? Will there ever be an input for which this if condition actually matter?

Comment: Please format your code correctly and decide whether you are using C or C++.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting and the tags.

Comment: It may get changed during the swap, but there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have defined min = i in the outer loop, the condition is always satisfied and thus, you can optimize your code by removing the condition.

In selection sort, you can also make more optimisations. Instead of swapping values each time a new minimum is found, you can find the position of the true minimum, say a[pos] and then swap it with the a[i].

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `min = i;` just before the j loop and there is no change happening inside the loop in the value of i and min, So, whatever be the case, arr[min] will always be equal to arr[i], evaluating if condition to be always true, so there is no role of these lines. Remove the condition, your code will become faster (if compiler is not optimising the code).